# Finding the number of possible solutions for a system of equations using the ball-dash method

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, generating-functions

> Determine the coefficient of $x^5$ in the expansion of $(x^2+2x+5)^5$.

By Leibniz's polynomial, we have
$$\sum\frac{5!}{a!b!c!}x^{2a+b} 2^b 5^c.$$
Now we just need to analyze the possibilities for
\begin{cases} 2a+b=5 \\ a+b+c=5\end{cases}
I would like to know how to know the number of possible solutions that this solution can have, in advance without trying to analyze each value that satisfies it. I thought about finding out using the ball-dash method, but I don't know how to do that...

Comment: you're missing an exponent maybe it should be ( )^5

Comment: It is clear that a=c. so We have only 2a+b=5, the number of solutions will be ceil(5/2)=3 which are (a=c=0, b=5), (a=c=1, b=3), (a=c=2, b=1)

Comment: @Mehdi I know, in this case, there are 3 possible solutions. I wanted to know a combinatorial calculation that would give me in advance the quantity of possible solutions I could have before conducting the analysis.

Comment: These numbers are small enough that you can list all solutions. Another approach is to expand each factor of $(x+1+2i)^5(x+1-2i)^5$ using the Binomial formula, and compute the coefficient that you need with the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Cauchy_product_of_two_power_series)

Comment: You can also use Maclaurin expansion. Take fifth derivative with respect to x, then set x to zero and divide it by 5!.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the ball-dash method, but we can find the coefficient of $x^5$ for instance by applying the binomial theorem twice. We use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^k$ of a series.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^5]}&\color{blue}{\left(x^2+2x+5\right)^5}\\
> &=[x^5]\sum_{k=0}^{5}\binom{5}{k}\left(x^2+2x\right)^k5^{5-k}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{5}\binom{5}{k}[x^{5-k}](x+2)^k5^{5-k}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{5}\binom{5}{k}\binom{k}{5-k}2^{2k-5}5^{5-k}\tag{2}\\
> &=\binom{5}{3}\binom{3}{2}2\cdot 5^2+\binom{5}{4}\binom{4}{1}2^3\cdot 5
> +\binom{5}{5}\binom{5}{0}2^5\\
> &=1\,500+800+32\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=2\,332}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the rule $[x^p]x^qA(x)=[x^{p-q}]A(x)$.
- In (2) we select the coefficient of $x^{5-k}$.